# How to write on a specific line of a file using c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code which generates a html file. The problem is to write on line 3 of my file like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    //here i need to write <title>sth</title>
  </head>
```

This is the function I tried and is not working :(

```cpp
void create_title(string a) {
  file.open("CTML.txt", ios::app || ios::in);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
  file.seekp(file.tellg());
  file << "<title>"<< a << "</title>" << endl;
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: The easiest technique:  don't modify the original file.  Write text from original file + modifications to a new file.  Files are not line oriented.  Text lines are variable records and a pain to modify in the original file (especially when the new text is longer than the original text).

Comment: That seems very tough. However you can read the file into buffer in memory. Then do modifications. Then write the modified content to new file. Then delete the original file. finally rename the new file with modified content as the original.

Comment: both were usefull thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I would suggest that you read the text into a std::string, while modifying it, and then put it back in the file. To do that, you need to read the file line by line, ignore the 3rd line and put something else instead, and then write it all back in the file.
I would suggest a code like this:

```
#include <fstream> // Header with file io functions

void create_title(std::string str) {
    std::ifstream file("CTML.txt"); // Open the file.
    std::string new_file_content = "";
    std::string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // Read the first two lines of the file into new_file_content.
        std::getline(file, line);
        new_file_content += line + '\n';
    }
    std::getline(file, line); // Skip 3rd line
    new_file_content += "<title>" + str + "</title>"; // Put modified 3rd line in new_file_content instead.
    while (std::getline(file, line)) // Read the rest of the file in new_file_content.
        new_file_content += line + '\n';
    file.close(); // Close the file.
    std::ofstream file_for_out("CTML.txt"); // Open the file for writing.
    file_for_out << new_file_content; // Write the new file content into the file.
}
```

Have a nice day, Amelia.
PS: I haven't tested the code, but it should work.